# Apache - LDAP basic auth checked but not required

Tags: ldap, authentication, apache2, proxypass, http-basic-authentication

I need Apache, configured as Proxy pass, to check the `Authorization: Basic ...` header against an LDAP server, setting a custom header if credentials exist and are correct but passing the request to the downstream server even if auth is missing or plain wrong.

I tried the following configuration:

```
      <Location ~ /my/path/(.*)/my/resource(/.+)?>
        AuthType Basic
        AuthName "Login with user id"
        AuthBasicProvider ldap
        AuthUserFile /dev/null
        AuthLDAPURL "my LDAP url"
        AuthLDAPBindDN "my bind variables"
        AuthLDAPBindPassword ******
        RequestHeader set X-Authenticated-User %{AUTHENTICATE_uid}e
        SetEnv 1 noauth
        <RequireAny>
           Require valid-user
           Require env noauth
        </RequireAny>
        ProxyPreserveHost On
        ProxyPass        http://downstream.server/my/other/path/$1/$2
        ProxyPassReverse http://downstream.server/my/other/path/$1/$2
     </Location>
```

But this way the `X-Authenticated-User` is always `(null)` even with valid credentials, probably because Apache optimises and doesn't perform the check at all.

I could manage to have `(null)` if the password mismatches or is not present at all.

My requirement is that the request is *always* sent to the downstream server, with the `X-Authenticated-User` set to the given username only if the password matches.

I edited the configuration: if I comment the `Require env noauth` line the basic auth works properly.